# std::mutex in shared memory not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, shared-memory, stdmutex

I have a scenario where the shared memory area is exclusively accessed by two different processes. When I launch the processes, the first process successfully locks the mutex, updates the memory and unlock the mutex. But I observe that when the second process try to lock it, it is still in deadlock state, waiting for mutex to unlock.

Time difference between the mutex lock is 10s for first and second process.

I am using the std::mutex. Please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And I'm not sure `std::mutex` is the correct primitive to use here, it might use process-specific data (to help with inter-*thread* synchronization). You should procably use your platforms cross-process mutex or semaphore instead.

Comment: Please, provide an example of what you're trying to do in order to well understand your potential mistakes.

Comment: Please provide us the code of the program as minimal as it can be.
We need to see the code to tell you if there is an error

Comment: std::mutex is not an interprocess mutex. You may want to consider using the boost.interprocess library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++11 interprocess atomics and mutexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161153/c11-interprocess-atomics-and-mutexes)

Answer (score 13):

Despite the citations that others have made to documentation, the classes `std::mutex` and `std::shared_mutex` **actually do work** across processes when used in shared memory on Linux. I've checked with GCC 8.3.1 and Clang 6.0.1.

Standard C++ implementations of these on Linux use pthreads. The pthreads provision of `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` and `PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE` as attributes for `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_rwlock_t` are abstracted out and defaulted 
by `std::mutex` and `std::shared_mutex`.  Even though POSIX documentation says that the default is PRIVATE, a `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_rwlock_t` allocated in shared memory will block competing processes when locked. *This is because the actual implementation of pthreads on Linux uses futexes*, and they are intended for use in shared memory even in cases where mapped addresses may differ across processes.

It's possible that the PTHREADS_PROCESS_PRIVATE behaviour is actually more difficult to implement given the strategy of using futexes to implement mutexes, and as such, is silently not implemented.

If you did want your mutexes to be process-private, just avoid putting them in shared memory. On the other hand if you do want to share them, be cautious that this standards discrepancy could be subject to change.

For reliability, use [Boost Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

Answer (score 6):

An std::mutex instance is only scoped to a single process; it is not capable of interprocess synchronization/concurrency. It is only capable of synchronizing child threads within a parent process.

Look to use Boost or an interprocess synchronization library instead.

Answer (score 1):

std::mutex does not support interprocess operation but pthread library has interprocess mutex that you can use. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20326345/4618618).