# synchronize between process with multiple threads in cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, mutex

I know how to synchronize between process and how to synchronize between threads. But I don't know how to synchronize between process with multiple threads.

Consider a scenario

I am creating 10 threads in a process. Each thread is printing a number.

I am running 10 processes simultaneously.

Now I need to create synchronization between process and threads such that at last, it should print 100 unique numbers in the console.Kindly note i don't expect the numbers printed in console to be in sequence , but all 100 numbers printed should be unique.

Kindly note that this idea should not only be limited to the above task. It may happen that I want to only one thread of one of the processes to execute certain code.

How to write this program in CPP for redhat.

Kindly note the version: gcc version 4.4.7.

Comment: cpp does not provide any specific inter-process communication features. you can use any of hundreds of available IPC methods directly from libc or from other libraries. e.g. pipes, shared memory semaphores, fifos, ...

Comment: @Serge I don't have any idea how to do it using shared memory semaphores. It will be kind of u if u could help me.

Comment: It will depend on your tools, but my general expectation would be that process-shared synchronization objects (mutexes, semaphores, *etc*.) will serve your inter-thread synchronization requirements, too.  That is, you ought to be able to synchronize the activity of multiple threads across multiple processes with one set of synchronization objects.

Comment: Synchronization is usually about resources.  Your statement seems to be more one of synchronizing output than of processes.  So it seems that one way to do it is to have one overarching process have a semaphore for the console, where each thread has to acquire exclusive control of the console via that semaphore.  What you use as a semaphore really depends on the operating environment

Comment: You might want to look at [boost::interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).  Also note that gcc 4.4.7 is old and may even be missing certain `c++11` features.

Comment: @JohnBollinger with synchronization , it should be able to generate unique numbers as explained above

Comment: Add an extra process that takes the output (with `select(2)`, for example) from the 10 other processes and interleaves them.

Comment: @infixed please read the edit done in question

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161153/c11-interprocess-atomics-and-mutexes   But if you want to deal with interprocess, perhaps you should start looking at `man sem_overview` too.  Which is more C than C++

Comment: Yes, @AbhishekGarg, and what?  I took you to be saying that you already know how to use synchronization to solve the problem, and were merely uncertain about how to synchronize threads belonging to different processes.  If that is not actually the case then this question is much too broad for SO.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i did it using lockf() , it did not work as expected

Comment: Try mpi, it's pretty good at synchronizing processes

Comment: Then actually, no, you do *not* know (very well) how to synchronize between processes.  I suppose you could use your `flock()` lock to synchronize between the processes, and when each process runs, let each of its threads run with appropriate inter-thread synchronization within the process.  The more elegant way, however, would be to use a genuine IPC mechanism, such as a [POSIX semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), to synchronize the threads directly.

Comment: so @JohnBollinger by using named semaphore as mentioned [here]<http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html> , it will synchronize between process with multiple threads in cpp.

Comment: you need to figure out which method is the best for you. google it. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372198/best-way-for-interprocess-communication-in-c

Comment: We can use Boost.Interprocess .Thanks guys for your comments